# How to declare a variable when it's value is an object composed with a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have several objects in a JSON formatted file with same string but different values :

```
{
    "object_1": {
        "data1": [1, -1],
        "data2": [2, -1],
        "data3": [3, -1],
    },
    "object_2": {
        "data1": [4, -1]
        "data2": [5, -1],
        "data3": [6, -1],
    }
}
```

I'm able to retrieve the data in the objects with `getJSON()` :

```
var url = "https://website.com/file.json";
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    var mydata1 = json.object_1.data1; 
    var mydata2 = json.object_1.data2; 
    var mydata3 = json.object_1.data3; 
});
```

But I have several objects and I don't want to duplicate the same three lines for all of them. I would like to create these variables `mydata1` `mydata2` and `mydata3` by using a function with the object id as an input.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to create a variable when it's value is an object composed with a variable. For example here `id` is a variable used to select the JSON objet : `object_1` or `object_2`.

```
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {

    var id = 1 // use id = 1 on page load

    function loadJSON(id) {

        // all these declaration fail
        eval("var mydata1 = string.concat('json.object_', id, '.data1')"); 
        var mydata1 = string.concat("json.object_", id, ".data1");  
        var mydata1 = window["json.object_" + id + ".data1"];
    );

    // then rewrite the data on click

    $('#button_2').click(function () { 
        loadJSON(2);    
    });     
    $('#button_1').click(function () {    
        loadJSON(1);    
    });

)},
```

How can I declare these variables in a function ?

Thank you,

Comment: What you're trying to do can only be done with `eval()`, but there's really no point. Instead of using individual variables, use an object and construct the object property names.

Comment: `json['object_'+id].data1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to reference value by variable property name:

```
var mydata1 = json['object_' + id].data1;
```